# Animating images in Watch OS2 not working

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm trying to animate the background image of a `WKInterfaceGroup` without success. I know this is something easy and shouldn't take to much to do it, but I still can't make the images animate.

I have six images loaded in the assets, named loading1 ~ loading 6.

I have the group set in IB, and have an `outlet` defined in my `WKInterfaceController`.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
    // Defined outlet from IB    
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKInterfaceGroup *mainGroup;
```

...

```
[self.mainGroup setBackgroundImageNamed:@"loading1"];

NSRange range = {1,6};
[self.mainGroup startAnimatingWithImagesInRange:range duration:0.5f repeatCount:0];
```

This does nothing. No image is shown. If I remove the `startAnimatingImagesInRange:duration:repeatCount:` method call, the image `loading1` is shown but, as expected, it doesn't animate.

I've tried also setting the animation in IB and calling `startAnimating` from code but it still has the same behaviour (when calling `startAnimating` the image disappears).

**NOTE**: I'm trying this in the simulator as I still don't have a Watch (do you think this might be the issue?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
[self.mainGroup setBackgroundImageNamed:@"loading1"];
```

to

```
[self.mainGroup setBackgroundImageNamed:@"loading"];
```

Comment: I really can't express in this 600 characters how thankful I'm for this answer.